# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"ChatScreen"} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'ChatScreen'?

Tags: react-native

here is my App.js which is the entry point. i get the error The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"ChatScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'ChatScreen'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production. and i have the ChatScreen in screens directory

```
import react from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import MainTabScreen from './scr/components/MainTabScreen';
import { DrawerContent } from './scr/components/DrawerContent';


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>

{/* screenOptions={{headerStyle:{
        backgroundColor: '#009387',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle:{
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      } */}

<Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>

      
        <Drawer.Screen 
         options={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
        name='md' component={MainTabScreen} />
        
        {/* <Drawer.Screen name="Products" component={Products} /> */}
      </Drawer.Navigator>
     
    </NavigationContainer> 
  );
}
```

here is my MainTbScreen.js which contains the navigation

```
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import HomeScreen from '../screens/Homescreen'
import Ministries from '../screens/Ministries'
import ProfileScreen from '../screens/ProfileScreen'

import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import ChatScreen from '../screens/ChatScreen';


const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const DetailsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const MainTabScreen = () => (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      activeColor="#fff"
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarColor: '#009387',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={DetailsStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Chat',
          tabBarColor: '#1f65ff',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="Messagebox" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Chat"
        component={ChatScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarColor: '#694fad',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="person" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarColor: '#d02860',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="ios-aperture" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
);

export default MainTabScreen;

const HomeStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
<HomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#009387',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    }}>
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{
        title:'Overview',
        headerLeft: () => (
            <Icon.Button name="ios-menu" size={25} backgroundColor="#009387" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}></Icon.Button>
        )
        }} />
</HomeStack.Navigator>
);

const DetailsStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
<DetailsStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#1f65ff',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    }}>
        <DetailsStack.Screen name="Details" component={Ministries} options={{
        headerLeft: () => (
            <Icon.Button name="ios-menu" size={25} backgroundColor="#1f65ff" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}></Icon.Button>
        )
        }} />
</DetailsStack.Navigator>
);
```

Comment: Can you show me how you want to navigate to `ChatScreen`? Maybe you have called navigation.navigate("ChatScreen") instead of `navigation.navigate("Chat")`

Comment: `<DrawerItem 
                            icon={({color, size}) => (
                                <Icon 
                                name="account-outline" 
                                color={color}
                                size={size}
                                />
                            )}
                            label="Chats"
                            onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('ChatScreen')}}
                        />
                        <DrawerItem `

Comment: Try `navigation.navigate("Chat")` instead of ChatScreen.

Comment: changed to `navigation.navigate('Chat') ` now good how comes so i can get the idea to edit the others @DavidScholz

Comment: You need to call the navigation on `name` defined in the screen not the component name. If you set `name` to `ChatScreen` in the navigator prop it works as well.

Comment: works welll now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are navigating using `ChatScreen` but this is not the name that you have defined in the `Screen` inside the navigator's `name prop`.

Either, do

```js
<Tab.Screen
        name="ChatScreen"
        component={ChatScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarColor: '#694fad',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="person" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
/>
```

or `navigation.navigate("Chat")` while leaving `name="Chat"`.

Comment: `const HomeScreen = ({navigation})=>{
 
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Homescreen 1</Text>
        <Button title='Go to Updates page'
        onPress={()=> navigation.navigate(Updates)} />
</View>
    )
  }

  export default HomeScreen;`   what now do i do to navigate between the pages

Comment: It works the same. You can navigate to all screens that are defined in a navigator as a screen.